# SQL DEVELOPER: Add time to date format

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in my database with the attributes start and end time.
These have the date format 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24: MI: SS'.
I would like to add a default value for the end time, which is the result of the start time plus 45 minutes.
Does anyone know how this could be implemented?

Kind regards

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA7sL.png)

Comment: Hi.  Please edit the question and show the exact table definition (columns, data types), exact sample data, and expected output for that data.

Comment: I think you would need to use a BEFORE INSERT trigger to do that.

Comment: I added a picture showing the code.

Comment: The `DEFAULT` expression cannot contain a reference to another column - that is stated very clearly in the documentation. As OldProgrammer said, you will need a trigger for that. Moreover, note that your `CREATE` statement has other errors - I noticed one right at the top, you should have `CREATE TABLE ...` (you are missing the mandatory keyword `TABLE`).

Comment: _"I added a picture showing the code"_   Many sites block such links for security reasons.  And many forum members refuse to open them for the same reasons.  Nothing stop you from pasting images directly into your posts.  And beyond that, it is preferable that code be posted _as text_, so that people can copy and paste it into their own systems for testing.   See [minimal reproducible example]{https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example}

Answer (score 1):

You may use `VIRTUAL` column instead of a `DEFAULT` value

The [virtual column](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1) is never inserted, but calculated in select from the given formula.

**Example**

```
create table lesson
(starttime DATE,
 endtime DATE generated always as (starttime +  INTERVAL '45' MINUTE) virtual
 );
 
insert into lesson(starttime) values(sysdate);
 
select * from lesson; 

STARTTIME           ENDTIME            
------------------- -------------------
14.12.2021 19:11:34 14.12.2021 19:56:34
```

**Real Default Value with Virtual Column**

If you want to be able to override the dafault value and change the length of the lesson - add an other column with the *exceptional* end time and adapt the formula.

```
create table lesson
(starttime DATE,
 endtime_exept DATE,
 endtime DATE generated always as (
    case when endtime_exept is null then starttime +  INTERVAL '45' MINUTE else endtime_exept end
    ) virtual
 );
 
insert into lesson(starttime) values(to_date('14.12.2021 10','dd.mm.yyyy hh24'));
 
select starttime, endtime from lesson; 

STARTTIME           ENDTIME            
------------------- -------------------
14.12.2021 10:00:00 14.12.2021 10:45:00

-- prolong the lesson
update lesson
set endtime_exept = to_date('14.12.2021 11','dd.mm.yyyy hh24');

select starttime, endtime from lesson;

STARTTIME           ENDTIME            
------------------- -------------------
14.12.2021 10:00:00 14.12.2021 11:00:00
```

Comment: This is not the equivalent of a default value as the `endtime` cannot be set to a value other than one 45 minutes after the start time.

Comment: Adpted the solution to cover the posibilty of changing the deaflt value without using trigger that I do not like @MT0

Comment: @MarmiteBomber  Now you are carrying around an extra column in the table that probably has no functional value to the application, no?  How is that cleaner than a trigger?

Comment: The *extra* column has  *indeed* a functional meaning, saying if filled - this lesson is *exceptional*  and does not fit in the grid. It will IMO remain in 99.9% null (my school experience), so you not only save space, but can savely *move* the standard hour only by updating the starttime. I'm not saying triggers are bad @OldProgrammer I do not like them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger and add an interval literal to the start time when the end time is `NULL`:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER lesson_default_endtime
  BEFORE INSERT ON lesson
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  IF :new.endtime IS NULL THEN
    :new.endtime := :new.starttime + INTERVAL '45' MINUTE;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

If you:

```sql
-- Default value
INSERT INTO lesson (starttime, endtime) VALUES (DATE '2021-01-01', NULL);

-- Non-default value
INSERT INTO lesson (starttime, endtime) VALUES (DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-01' + INTERVAL '1' HOUR);
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT starttime, endtime FROM lesson;
```

Outputs:

> | STARTTIME | ENDTIME |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 00:45:00 |
> | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2021-01-01 01:00:00 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=80c89d7bf5e786178103140088c90a1c)*